# How to download images async for WidgetKit

Tags: ios, swiftui, urlsession, widgetkit

I am developing Widgets for iOS and I really don't know how to download images for the widgets.

The widget currently downloads an array of Objects, and every object has a URL of an image. The idea is that every object makes a `SimpleEntry` for the `Timeline`.

What's the best way of achieving this? I read that Widgets shouldn't use the `ObservableObject`. I fetch the set of objects in the timeline provider, which seems to be what Apple recommends. But do I also download the images there and I wait until all are done to send the timeline?

Any advice would be very helpful,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you should download the images in the timeline provider and send the timeline when they are all done. Refer to the following [recommendation](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/652581?answerId=618126022#618126022) by an Apple frameworks engineer.

I use a dispatch group to achieve this.
Something like:

```
let imageRequestGroup = DispatchGroup()
var images: [UIImage] = []
for imageUrl in imageUrls {
    imageRequestGroup.enter()
    yourAsyncUIImageProvider.getImage(fromUrl: imageUrl) { image in
        images.append(image)
        imageRequestGroup.leave()
    }
}
imageRequestGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
    completion(images)
}
```

I then use SwiftUI's Image(uiImage:) initializer to display the images

Comment: This is the best solution at the moment. 

I used SDWebImage in my widget and this technique works reliably across iOS, iPadOS and macOS (Catalyst) (The host app, Widget will be native)

Comment: Should we use this inside "getTimeline(for configuration..." ? and when call completion(timeline) inside it!?

Comment: @Ahmadreza Yes, that's the way I'm using it.

Comment: @dezinezync You mean "loading the images before returning the timeline" is the best solution at the moment? Because if you use `SDWebImage`'s `WebImage` inside the widget view it will load the image while the view is rendered right?

Comment: @fruitcoder yes. So by calling it in the timeline method, you're essentially pre-warming the SDWebImage cache so when its requested by the renderer, it's either immediately available or not in case the loading failed.

Comment: I used this function to get an image
  
func downloadImage(url: URL, completion: @escaping (UIImage?) -> Void) {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
      do {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
        let image = UIImage(data: data)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
          completion(image)
        }
      } catch {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
          completion(nil)
        }
      }
    }
  }

Answer (score 1):

I dont have a good solution, but I try to use `WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()`, and it make sence.
In the following code.

```
var downloadImage: UIImage?

func downloadImage(url: URL) -> UIImage {
    
    var picImage: UIImage!
    
    if self.downloadImage == nil {
        
        picImage = UIImage(named: "Default Image")
        
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            do {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.downloadImage = UIImage.init(data: data)
                    if self.downloadImage != nil {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch { }
        }
    } else {
        picImage = self.downloadImage
    }
    
    return picImage
}
```

Also you have to consider when to delete this picture.
This like `tableView.reloadData()`.